# Auto-assign default value - Prisma / Next.js 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

When I add a new movie with the form, I want it to have the category with the id 'all-films' by default. How can i do this? Thanks in advance. Here are the codes:

new-film.tsx -->

```
const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        id:"",
        name: "",
        imageUrl: "",
        filmUrl: "",
    }
})

const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    try {
        await axios.post("/api/films", values)
        
        form.reset()
        router.refresh()
        onClose()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

api/films/route.ts -->

```
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request){
    try {
        const { id, name, imageUrl, filmUrl } = await req.json()

        const film = await db.film.create({
            data: {
                id,
                name,
                imageUrl,
                filmUrl
            }
        })

        return NextResponse.json(film)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("[GAMES_POST]", error);
        return new NextResponse("Internal Error", {status: 500})
    }
}
```

schema.prisma -->

```
model Category {
  id String @id
  name String
  imageUrl String @db.Text

  films Film[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}

model Film {
  id String @id
  name String
  imageUrl String @db.Text
  filmUrl String @db.Text

  category Category[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

When I add a new movie with the form, I want it to have the category with the id 'all-films' by default. How can i do this? Thanks in advance. Here are the codes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
    const film = await db.film.create({
        data: {
            id,
            name,
            imageUrl,
            filmUrl,
            category: {
                connect: { id: 'all-films' }
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to edit your POST-function and at catgory as a new parameter and to fill it:

```
const categoryId = "all-films"
const film = await db.film.create({
  data: {
    id,
    categoryId,
    name,
    imageUrl,
    filmUrl
    }
  })
```

If you want the user to be able to select a category and just have it pre-filled you need to expand your form and then add a default value (you already have some empty ones it would seem):

```
const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        id:"",
        categoryId: "all-films",
        name: "",
        imageUrl: "",
        filmUrl: "",
    }
})
```